Quarternions in the graph editor
So I have some existing animation that appears to have been keyframe with Quarernions and I understand that we shouldn't really directly access the attributes because they're not directly related to XYZ. I believe this animation must have been keyframed visually.
So the graph editor also shows the keyframes in quaternions and therefore how can I edit the curves in the graph editor when I have a W channel affecting everything?
Is there a way to convert? I've not used Blender than long so I may be missing something really obvious (hopefully!)
Thanks in advance
Paul
